# Error while creating a SVN branch from terminal on mac

Tags: macos, svn, version-control

I am getting an error while creating a new branch for trunk on mac. I am using terminal to create it. This is the command i am using:

svn copy svn://server/path/to/trunk svn://server/path/to/branch/newBranch -m "Cut branch: newBranch"

And, I am getting following errors:

svn: E175008: At least one property change failed; repository is unchanged
svn: E175002: Server sent unexpected return value (400 Bad Request) in response to PROPPATCH request for 'somePathForNewBranch'

Please let me know how can i resolve it.

Comment: Please suggest something on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried changing network and it worked perfectly. No Clue, What was going wrong out there.